# Issue with tSytsem component escape chars

Tags: unix, talend

I am trying to execute unix cmd in tSystem component , however component is throwing an error, Can someone please help me? Can you point me what I need to do to handle double quote and single quote in a cmd ? I treid escape but its not helping much

Working cmd:

```
touch /dir/datadir/data.csv ; awk -F'"' 'NF&&NF%2==0{ORS=ORS==RS?" ":RS}1' /dir/datadir/data.csv | tail -n +2> /dir/datadir/temp.csv ; touch /dir/datadir/temp.csv
```

Talend cmd:

```
new String[]{"/bin/bash","-c","touch "+context.Dir+"datadir/"+((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE"))+"; awk -F '"' 'NF&&NF%2==0{ORS=ORS==RS?" ":RS}1' "+context.Dir+"datadir/"+((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE"))+" tail -n +2> "+context.Dir+"datadir/temp.csv ; touch "+context.Dir+"datadir/temp.csv" ;}
```

Comment: Hi - can you provide the error message you are seeing? Can you show the actual command that Talend is executing - having replaced all the variables/references with actual values -  (taken from a log file or from the Unix box)? Thanks

Comment: the cmd itself working fine, however in talend double quote is causing an issue and it says invalid cmd

Comment: Yes, but the Talend command that you've given is not what is actually being executed - it is full of variables that Talend will replace with actual values before executing. I want to see the final command so that I know how Talend has converted what you've given to what it is actually executing.